# object is moving in the accelerometer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer, ccsprite, acceleration

I want to create one game in cocos2d in which one object is running .

I want to move this object from left and right base on device accelerometer.
I am getting the value of the accelerometer and update the location of the object. even I can see the new location in the LOG. but the object is not moving from it's possion. here it the code which I have writen in the app .

> ```
> - (void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration1 {
>
> acceleration = acceleration1;
> CGPoint position = mainPlayer.position;
>
> if(acceleration.y < -0.25) {  // tilting the device to the right
>     position.y -= 0.25;
> } else if (acceleration.y > 0.25) {  // tilting the device to the left
>     position.y += 0.25;
> } else {
>
> } //    newPosition = position;
>
> CCAction *action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.01 position:position];
> [mainPlayer runAction:action]; 
> //    mainPlayer.position = ccp(position.x, position.y);
> }
> ```

I have try both way by setting position direct and by using action.

Dose any one knows why this problem is occure or any setting need for accelerometer to work.

Please give any link for such kind example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using MoveBy instead of MoveTo:

```
 - (void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration1 {

    acceleration = acceleration1;
    CGPoint position = ccp(0,0);

    if(acceleration.y < -0.25) {  // tilting the device to the right
        position.y = 0.25;
    } else if (acceleration.y > 0.25) {  // tilting the device to the left
        position.y = 0.25;
    }

    CCAction *action = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.01 position:position];
    [mainPlayer runAction:action]; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise not to run actions from the accelerometer as this method is called like 10 times in a second (I dont remember how cocos2d initialize the accelerometer) which will cause the `runAction` method to be called 10 times a second and probably stops the previous action which is why you do not see it moving.

Show more code regarding on how you create your main player and how you add it to the scene/layer